# Use a 110V switch to activate a 3-phase motor 240V

Tags: electrical, electric-motor

I have a 110V switch on a control panel that will be used to turn on/off a 3-phase 240V motor. Power has already been run to each item and now I need to figure out how to use the switch to control the motor. Is a relay the only way to accomplish this or is there another way?

Answer (score 3):

You DO NOT want a definite purpose contactor for a 3-phase motor. You need a motor starter. And a 3-phase switch like shown above is a disconnect switch. It IS NOT designed to start or control motors.

Motor starters have finely tuned overloads so that if any leg drops, or the amperage goes too high on any leg, the starter will shut down the motor. 3-phase motors WILL run on single phase once they are running and this WILL burn them up in short order. You MUST have this protection from running on single phase.

That said, this IS NOT a DIY job, especially considering the tone and nature of your question. So I personally will not provide links or instructions of any kind. Please contact a qualified electrician in your area.